# To hide "user defined completion" message at vim

Tags: vim

The message is at bottom of vim, `User defined completion ^U^P^N`.

This info is no use for me.

Is it possible to hide the message?

I try to use

```
imap silent ^Y ^X^U
```

set on vimrc

But neither of the popmenu and message show.

Note:
I find this issue at github. If you are insteresting in this question, you can also read the issue.

[click me](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/39)

[image]

Comment: You seem to use an autocompletion plugin (neocomplete?), I don't think what you ask is possible but you should ask the author of that plugin.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I consider my question will happen without any plugin, so I didn't report the issue.

Comment: for anyone experiencing the same problem, please accept the last answer! (`set shortmess+=c`) @ShawnHuang

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hide that message by setting the option

```
:set noshowmode
```

But this will also hide the current mode (insert, visual, ...) and I guess some other stuff.

Comment: Maybe I can use this setting and the airline plugin. But the green text is still. Could I ask one more question that is how to turn off the text? Thank you.

Comment: Well your first question was clearly for the 'User defined completion ^U^P^N' part. So I guess you can ask another question for the other part.

Answer (score 8):

better late than never (not quite sure which version this starts at)...

add the "c" flag to shortmess:

`:set shortmess+=c`

from the vim docs:

```
c     don't give ins-completion-menu messages.  
      For example, 
      "-- XXX completion (YYY)", "match 1 of 2", 
      "The only match",
      "Pattern not found", "Back at original", etc.
```

Furthermore, make sure you do that after using 'set compatible' because if you don't, it will be set back to it's default after the fact. Also, some pesky plugins like to change things like this on their own, it might be worth checking to see if any script is removing the 'c' flag from your settings. [ I have some plugins that do that and it makes me tear my hair out. ]

NOTE: I am pretty sure this is a very late feature, meaning you will have to compile if you want it.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to turn that off. You'd have to modify the Vim sources and compile your own binary. Granted, this doesn't provide much information (you know which keys you've pressed to trigger that completion), but your focus should be on the completion menu far away, anyway.

Comment: To recompile source code can be the solution, but I still want to use original vim.

Comment: And to recompile the source code is a calling the kettle black. Of course anything can be accomplished that way, so i wouldn't  even bother with thinking about that. Previously, rewriting the plugin may not help either, sacrificing lack of mode display over hiding the message is also a no, unless you have it in that easy mode, which imo, severely cripples vim. Once you start needing features like that I would have to say, move on to an IDE better suited if you can unless you are stuck in term mode and cant use a gui.